# How to align 2 image view in a row?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, apk

this is my xml code i want to set two images in row

**XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:tint="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-52dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_karo"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:tint="#0000b3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In Android Studio Preview, It's looking perfect as I want. But when I install APK in a device, It's not working

Android Studio Preview:

[image: img1]

This is my Device Preview:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Linera Layout instead Constraint Layout or Linear Leyout within parent Constraint Layout. You can directly use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_2"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:tint="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-52dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_karo"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:tint="#0000b3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if i use your code then 1st image in left and 2nd in right. but i want in center

Comment: You should add layout_gravity as centre for both the ImageView. In your current code, layout_gravity is 'left' and 'right' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment add layout_gravity as centre in both the ImageView. I have also edited the code as you can not use text in Image View.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_karo"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this will work perfectly for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try with Linear Layout

Like this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:tint="#ff0000"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-52dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="340dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:tint="#0000b3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your question you can use Constraint layout property to set two images in row :-

Start to Start

End to End

Start to End

End to Start

for example :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_share"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_share"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_save"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```